# ICloud, and iPhoto

Tags: ipad, photos, photo-stream

When I have some downtime, I try to tidy up, and delete photos on my iPad, but only some of the photos have a delete button. Is this because those particular photos (ones without a delete option), were not taken on the ipad? With photo streaming, you can end up with thousands of photos, and I often will take a photo of something as a reminder, instead of writing it down. But then when it comes time to delete said reminder photo, I can't.

Answer (score 1):

Pictures that can't be deleted on your camera roll were [synced from iTunes](http://m.imore.com/cant-delete-photo-albums-your-iphone-or-ipad-heres-why).

You can delete them or modify what is synced with iTunes on a Mac or PC.

If you don't have access to the computer with which you first synced those pictures to your device you can follow the steps described in this [Apple Support document](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204120) to delete them:

> 1. Create a folder on the computer that you now sync with, and add a single photo to that folder.
> 2. In the Photos tab in iTunes, click the box next to "Sync Photos From."
> 3. In the pop-up menu next to "Sync Photos From," choose the folder you created in step 1.
> 4. Apply the change.
> 5. Uncheck "Sync Photos From."
> 6. Apply the change again.
> 7. Your synced photos will now be removed from the device.

Note that you will lose those pictures with this method, so you may want to check if you have other copies, or save copies by sending them by email for instance.

Pictures taken with other devices when Photo Stream is activated can be deleted normally.
From the [My Photo Stream FAQ](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201317):

> How do I delete photos from My Photo Stream?
>
> You can delete photos from My Photo Stream on your iOS device or Mac when you tap (the trash icon) or click Delete.
>
> (...)
>
> When you delete a photo from My Photo Stream on one device, it will be removed from Photos and iCloud. The photos you import from My Photo Stream to your other devices won’t be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you use iCloud Photo Library then you should be able to delete any photo from any device since everything syncs with the servers. From [kbase HT204264](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264):

> Even the photos and videos you delete on one device, delete everywhere that you use iCloud Photo Library. And if you want to get back a photo that you deleted, you can find it in the Recently Deleted album for up to 30 days.

Before I switched to iCloud Photo Library I know I wasn't able delete photos that were synced from iTunes.

Answer (score -2):

The photos that you can't delete are synced to your iCloud from another device. If you want to delete them, you can delete them from the device they were taken on or (IIRC) delete them on iCloud.com.